# Windows phone 7 facebook app authentication issue

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I have tested many facebook samples but nothing seems to work if you target Windows Phone 7 platform.One of the samples is [this one](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application) . I copied all files in a new project targeting windows phone 7 but when i tap the Connect button and enter my facebook username,password there is just an icon of my facebook application and the description and no buttons to permit or not permit the application to have access at my account.

I also tested the Facebook C# SDK Sample with Windows Phone 7
https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows-phone-sample but the result is the same.If i target windows phone 8 platform it is working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to tried this:
http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/tutorial/

This may help because this works for me.

Comment: It seems there was a facebook issue because, one day after i posted this question all the examples i created were working great. The butttons to allow or cancel the autorization of the facebook application appeared without changing my code. Thanks for your answer.